# Podman port bind visualization

Tags: podman

I starting a container with two  specific ports like this:

```
podman run -d --name igfsbuynow -p 18080:18080 -p 18081:18081 igfsbuynow:5.5.0.17
```

The questions is that podman change the port rappresentation after the container activation.

 Example:
**podman ps -a**

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                          COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                                 NAMES
96c007a58074  localhost/igfsbuynow:5.5.0.17              11 seconds ago  Up 10 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:18080-18081->18080-18081/tcp  igfsbuynow
```

I expected to have this port binding result:

```
0.0.0.0:18080->18080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18081->18081/tcp
```

Do you know why this happend?

Podman version 4.0.2

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `0.0.0.0:18080-18081->18080-18081/tcp` and `0.0.0.0:18080->18080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18081->18081/tcp` mean the same thing? (just a guess)

Comment: Yes it is. Buy why this difference in the visualization?

Comment: The string seems to originate from the function  [`func portsToString(ports []types.PortMapping) string`](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/342c8259381b63296e96ad29519bd4b9c7afbf97/cmd/podman/containers/ps.go#L476-L502)   Maybe there are some clues in the [`git blame`](https://github.com/containers/podman/blame/v4.0.2/cmd/podman/containers/ps.go#L476-L502)